# Can I change the autocomplete to a dropdown for the entity_browser module?

Tags: media, configuration

I'd like to be able to change the autocomplete for the Site Sections portion of the entity_browser module.

I'm not seeing any way to modify this within the admin. Am I missing something? Can I do this in config? Do I need to create a custom patch?

[image]

Comment: You need to find the "Manage form display" page for the entity type/bundle behind that form. Probably a media type

Comment: @Clive that was the first thing I did and unfortunately it doesn't look like it exists.

Comment: Please update your question with more info. You should be able to find relevant settings under "Structure" menu item.